# Which word would be best when talking about collecting seafood in the ocean?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-choice, differences

I usually use the word "*collect*" to say taking seafood from the water.
Could I use the word "*harvest*" to say that?

E.g.

> "Harvesting seafood under the water is difficult."

Are there any other, better options? 
Perhaps "picking up" would fit.

Comment: I think "harvest" is the best word in the generic sense for "catching" molluscs and crustaceans for the table. What the French term Les fruits de mer, but excluding oysters

Comment: *Cockles* (clams) in the UK are usually gathered by *cockle pickers*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search of Google Ngrams would suggest the following (in order of use):

1. Harvest
2. Collect
3. Fish

[image: Ngrams Search]

However, I wouldn't trust *fish* which I added in as a possibility, as it might not be used as a verb.

Comment: if you search for "fish seafood", you find mostly phrases like: "Never refreeze fish, seafood or fish products", "a fish / seafood restaurant", or other instances of both words being nouns.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by **seafood**

There is the [dictionary definition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/seafood)

The [culinary definition](http://www.cooksinfo.com/seafood)

and this [much longer list](http://safereating.co.uk/problem-foods/fish-seafood-shellfish/)

Because of the variety of species which come under the heading of seafood and the differences in their lifestyles you need many different [techniques](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fishing_techniques) to catch them.

This means that the only word which can be applied to the taking of all types of **seafood** is **harvest**.